# How to get a value/row from pandas read_csv

Tags: python, pandas

I am using a CSV file with news about crypto. My goal is to practice string manipulation and methods. The CSV looks something like this :

```
publishdate headlinetext
20130504    COnSTELlATIon DaG iS nOW liStEd On kucoiN eXC?haNGE
20130511    ItA*lys cRypTOCUrREnCy BITgrAil suspeNds OpERatIOnS
20130511    THe diffeRENCe bETWEEn sHarEs aNd cRYpToCUrReN€CiES
20130512    fedS seIzE 47 mIlLION In bItCoinS in FAke ID ST=ing
20130514    ThE diG sTarteD ASiCboOST neTwORK AnD b@ItcoIN cAsH
20130516    BINAncE far atualiZAO progRaMadA NEsTa QuarTAFEIR?a
20130516    tHe EUropeaN UniOn IS pLaNninG tO rEgULAtE Bi=TcOIn
20130516    i!BeROBiT HELpiNG bItcOIn To GO MAinStream IN sPaIN
20130521    EuropES sMALLEr €banKS WELComE CrypTOcuRRENCy uSerS
20130604    BiTcoIn btc hIghER bTc= price BRiNgs mOrE Btc SCAmS
20130610    BITCOin brEAkS 9000 iN latEST LANDmARK Pr#iCE pOinT
20130613    ubcoiN mArkEt movEs ItS HEAdQUArTERS To €SiNgaPorE 
20130624    reeds jEwelErs TaKinG bitCOiN ONLiNe And IN Sto$Res
20130705    CoNtrOvE!RSY turnS to cLoSuRe as LItePAy SHUts DowN
20130709    bUll rESiSTAncE BITCOIn pRicE nEeDs brEAK AbOve 9K*
20130714    DIVoRcE DISpUte co#Uple fIghtS ovEr 830k Of BITcoin
20130718    10K agaIn For BitcoiN buT oT!her CRyptOs OUTperfORM
20130724    FACebOoKS liBRa crYptoCUrrency wHER$E aRE ThE BANkS
20130726    COULd eNjIn coiN ReacH A neW AlltiM=E hIGh in APRIL
20130827    the GReaT Tug of WaR betWE=eN bItCOiNS anD AltCOINs
20130827    The SacRAMento kINgs mINE EthEreuM ETh for C#HArItY
20130905    cryPtOCuRREncY aTMs tHE KEY T*o WIdeSPRead ADoPtiOn
20130909    GraySCales EtHereUM TRusT pRICE= VaLUeS Eth aT 6000
(...)
```

Then I used pandas to read the CSV.

```
import pandas as pd

news_headlines = pd.read_csv('/content/sample_data/crypto_headlines.csv')

news_headlines
```

Now I need to get the strings to work with them and change them to lower or upper case and then remove special characters.

However , I don't know which method I should use to extract a string from this variable I created called news_headlines.

Let's say I wanted to extract the 2nd row, with the publish date on  20130511.

Any help ?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`iloc()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.iloc.html), as in the example below, to extract the string related to the second row:

```
news_headlines.iloc[1, 1]
```

Comment: Yep , that method works but I had to change to  news_headlines.iloc[ 1 ]

Thanks !!